# What's differences between these protocol definition?

Tags: ios, swift

Recently, I'm a little confuse about the definition ways for protocol in swift.

`protocol OneDelegate : class`

or

`protocol OneDelegate : NSObjectProtocol`

or

`@objc protocol OneDelegate`

or

`@class_protocol protocol OneDelegate`

And shall we keep using weak for delegate? Or like 
 `unowned(unsafe) var dataSource: UITableViewDataSource?`

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first and last are actually the same. Both specify that a protocol can only be adopted by a class, i.e. a struct can't adopt the protocol. The form `protocol OneDelegate : class` is preferred. And `@class_protocol protocol OneDelegate` is deprecated.

The second case is a way to extend an existing protocol. Say for example you wanted your `UITableViewDelegate` to respond to a long press, then you could define a protocol:

```
protocol UITableViewDelegateWithRecognizer: UITableViewDelegate {
    func longPressed()
}
```

Then conformance to the protocol `UITableViewDelegateWithRecognizer` requires conformance to all the `UITableViewDelegate` functions, plus the extra method `longPressed`.

You need to use `@objc` if you intend to use the protocol in a file written in Objective-C. Additionally if you want to have an optional function declaration you need to use `@objc`.

Finally the same ARC rules for memory management apply to Swift as Objective-C, thus you will often want to use the `weak` specifier. One caveat is that a lot of Swift objects are value types, not reference types. And you cannot have a weak reference to a value type. So if you need to use a weak reference to avoid a retain-cycle, then you must specify that the protocol is a class protocol, i.e. your first example.